# Can files backup with the Windows 7 backup software be restored on Vista/XP

Tags: windows-7, backup

If I use the build in backup on Windows 7, then need to access a file from a Vista or XP machine, can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Vista, but not on XP:

> You can restore files from a backup
>   that was created on another computer
>   running Windows Vista or Windows 7.

[Restore files from a backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Restore-files-from-a-backup)